# Examples of iPhone apps written in Flash

Tags: iphone, flash

Hi
I've been trying to evaluate the maturity of Adobe's iPhone Packager
so i'm looking for examples of real apps, in the app store,
that were written in Flash (or FLEX)

Does anybody know any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone who is currently developing an iPhone/Android game using Flash, I can tell you it will be an uphill battle.  I can create a game that runs at 200+ fps on a browser (though I would never run it at that speed) that will only run at 20-24 on the iPhone.  And we're talking about an extremely, extremely optimized game that implements a different rendering engine for iPhone and Android.

Those devices are just so much weaker and the packager has been implmented in a generic enough way that it works for everything you create in Flash but it doesn't fully take advantage of an iPhone or Android's low-level GPU rendering.  Perhaps when Molehill comes out, it will be a different story.

With all that said, if you're creating a puzzle game or more of a basic application, you'll be fine.  If you're creating anything much more intensive, like side-scrollers and/or lots of animation & physics, you're going to be very disappointed.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of games, for instance [Chroma Circuit](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chroma-circuit/id331078068?mt=8) and [Gridshock](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gridshock/id354559751?mt=8).

The only non-game app I know offhand is [Visualator](http://www.creativeapplications.net/flash/visualator-flash-iphone-ipad/). I believe [Tesla Toy](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tesla-toy/id395767185?mt=8) is also built with Flash but I'm not sure.

Also, Adobe themselves have built the [Adobe Connect Mobile](http://itunes.apple.com/se/app/adobe-connect-mobile/id338279127?mt=8) app using the packager for iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Some nice people at GamingYourWay made a game for the iPhone with the CS5 beta. They also posted some good tips I thought would come in handy:

http://blog.gamingyourway.com/PermaLink,guid,7411978e-9a1d-408f-800f-4995799760c9.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This was a Web Game ported to iOS using Flash CS5

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/volcano-flight/id413995237?mt=8